# How can I apply target-specific compiler and linker flags to subdirectories in CMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, stm32

I am using CMake for a STM32 project as the project is outgrowing a plain Makefile. My directory structure looks something like what's below. I have an executable defined in the root `CMakeLists.txt` and `somelib` compiled as an OBJECT library which is added to the main `CMakeLists.txt` using `add_subdirectory`.

```
CMakeLists.txt
src/
├─ app/
│  ├─ main.c
├─ lib/
│  ├─ somelib/
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  │  ├─ somelib.h
│  │  ├─ somelib.c
```

I need to compile and link the source files with some flags specific to my microcontroller (i.e. `-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard`). I set up a toolchain file for the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler and handled the compiler-specific flags there, but I'm hesitant to put the microcontroller-specific flags in that toolchain file as well since this project could expand to where I'd want to run my project on a different microcontroller.

My problem is if I were to define the microcontroller specific flags in the root `CMakeLists.txt`, when it comes time to compile `somelib`, I don't know how I can get `somelib` to compile with those flags. I know that I could use the global `add_compile_options` and `add_libraries`, but that seems like a bad idea, especially if I want to support a different microcontroller in the same project as well that would have a different set of flags. How can I propagate compiler and linker settings to the subdirectories for a specific executable?

Comment: Maybe you want to look at M4 and autotools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm hesitant to put the microcontroller-specific flags in that toolchain file as well since this project could expand to where I'd want to run my project on a different microcontroller.

So don't be hesitant and do that. And when you will move to a different microcontroller, you will have a different toolchain file for it. Have one toolchain for every unique set of compiler flags. `-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard` flags definitely belong to a toolchain file.

---

When you want to support many many many toolchain files combinations and want to go a bit advanced, you might want to use the default behavior of sourcing `Platform/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}-GNU-C-${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}.cmake` file from CMake module search path. That, combined with some custom variables `-DUSE_FLOAT=hard/soft` and `-DMFPU=fpv4-sp-d16` makes a nice structure view.

Comment: I'll add that if you want a bunch of common settings between several toolchain files you can always `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/common.cmake")` to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: It didn't occur to me to create multiple toolchain file variants. Wouldn't that mean I need to reconfigure cmake to compile the executable on a different microcontroller though?

Comment: Yes, preferably, you would keep a separate build directory for every configuration, so that you can reuse build files. You may want to research cmake-presets and/or write custom scripts around that.